# Displaying keys and values of an object with jQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays, object

I am trying to display the keys and values of an object but I'm getting only an error saying:

`0[object Object]1[object Object]2[object Object]3[object Object]`

What am I doing wrong?

My object, according to `console.log` is:

```
(4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0
:
{text: "Now", time: "Now"}
1
:
{text: "09:00", time: "09:00"}
2
:
{text: "09:30", time: "09:30"}
3
:
{text: "10:00", time: "10:00"}
length
:
4
__proto__
:
Array(0)
```

I am trying t display it with:

```
var html='';
$.each( data.times, function( key, val ) { 
      html+=key+val;
});
createElement("times", html );
```

Comment: Your response don't have key called "times" thus data.times is nothing.

Comment: @amitwadhwani I've updated the output :)

Comment: Why you think `0[object Object]` is an "error"? `data.times` is an array of objects. `key` will be the index of the current element (`0, 1, 2, ...`) and `val` is the element (an object) at that index. Calling `.toString()` on one of these objects returns `[object Object]` -> `0[object Object]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is because `data.times` is an array of objects, which you are attempting to loop through as if it was an array of strings.

To fix this you need to instead loop through the *properties* of the object within the array, which you can achieve by using `Object.keys`, something like this:

```js
var data = {
  times: [{
    "09:00": "09:00",
    "09:30": "09:30",
    "10:00": "10:00"
  }]
}

var html = '';
Object.keys(data.times[0]).forEach(function(key) {
  html += key + '-' + data.times[0][key] + ' ';
});
console.log(html);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Note that this will only loop over the first object in the array as that's all your data structure contains. If you want to loop through more objects you'd need to add another loop around this logic.

---

*Post question edit update:*

Now that you've amended the data structure you can just loop through the objects in the array and access their keys directly:

```js
var data = {
  times: [
    { text: "Now", time: "Now" },
    { text: "09:00", time: "09:00" },
    { text: "09:30", time: "09:30" },
    { text: "10:00", time: "10:00" }
  ]
}

var html = '';
data.times.forEach(function(obj) {
  html += obj.text + '-' + obj.time + ' ';
});
console.log(html);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks! :) I realized my object doesn't make much sense so I updated the way it's output.

Comment: Ok, well firstly that's a completely different structure to what you first showed, and secondly it still doesn't make a great deal of sense.

Comment: That worked perfectly and makes sense. Thank you for taking the time in helping me. Greatly appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

Updated code.

```
$.each( data, function( key, val ) { 
      html+=key+val.time;
});
createElement("times", html );
```